# How to define class field in Python that is an instance of a class?

Tags: c#, python, metaprogramming

I want to get a specific class instance in the class's namespace. In C# this would look like this:

```
public struct Foo
{
    public readonly static Bar = new Foo();
}
```

The only idea I have is to assign an instance right after the class definition (monkeypatch):

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, spam):
        self.spam = spam
Foo.bar = Foo(42)
```

But I want to provide instance in class definition, like this:

```py
class Foo:
    ...
    bar = Foo(42)
```

And interface like this:

```py
from foo import Foo
bar = Foo.bar
```

The last line in definition gives a syntax error because Foo is not yet defined. Is there a way to overcome this constraint except monkeypatching class?

Comment: What problem exactly are you trying to solve with this design?

Comment: You don't need metaclasses in this case, custom descriptor is enough. See my answer.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque the main goal was to get specific instance of a class in class's namespace, as I said in question. What lead me to question, I was studying about functional programming concept, monoid. Monoid is an operation on two objects of the same class, which have a neutral element. For example, if we have class int, then addiction would be monoid with neutral element = 0. Same idea can be applied to more complex types, and I was thinking about clear ways to do this in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The requested functionality can be achieved with custom descriptor object ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html)):

```
class static_property:
    def __init__(self, getter):
        self.__getter = getter

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return self.__getter(objtype)

    @staticmethod
    def __call__(getter_fn):
        return static_property(getter_fn)

class A:
    _bar = None

    def __init__(self, spam):
        self.spam = spam

    @static_property
    def bar(cls):
        if cls._bar is None:
            cls._bar = A(10)
        return cls._bar

print('A.bar={} A.bar.spam={}'.format(A.bar, A.bar.spam))

a = A(20)
print('a.bar={} a.bar.spam={} a.spam={}'.format(a.bar, a.bar.spam, a.spam))
```

Prints:

```
A.bar=<__main__.A object at 0x7f0ab5e41eb8> A.bar.spam=10
a.bar=<__main__.A object at 0x7f0ab5e41eb8> a.bar.spam=10 a.spam=20
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Metaclasses for this then you can use following. I indeed don't know why you want to achieve this, or whether the method I present is good, but nevertheless it works well.

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        print(cls,name, bases, dct)
        x = super(Meta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        x.bar = x(46) //create the bar for the Foo
        return x




class Foo:
    __metaclass__ = Meta
    def __init__(self, spam):
        self.spam = spam
```

What this does is simply create a `bar` named attribute for the `Foo` while creating the object for the class. I guess the code is self explanatory

Answer (score 0):

To work at class level you need the `@classmethod` decorator.

```
class Foo:
   # Class variable
   Bar = None 

   def __init__(self, value): 
      self.val = value 
      Foo.update_Bar(self) 

   @classmethod 
   def update_Bar(cls, new_instance): 
      cls.Bar = new_instance

print(Foo.Bar is None)
foo1 = Foo(10)
print(Foo.Bar.val)
foo2 = Foo(20)
print(Foo.Bar.val)
print(foo1.Bar.val)
```

Comment: Yes, but I have to initialize Foo to work with Foo.Bar. Maybe there is a way to work directly on Foo.Bar? The only idea that comes to my mind is to create a poor man's singleton in some classmethod or make some weird metaclasses.

Comment: The whole idea on bar is that field not supposed to change at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it into an externally callable method, like :-

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data

    def update(self,value):
        self.bar = Foo(value)
        self.show()

    def show(self):
        print(self.bar.data,"Updated Successfully")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    node = Foo(None)

    node.update(10)
    node.update(20)
    node.update("Hello World")
```

The output of this code will be like :-

```
10 Updated Successfully
20 Updated Successfully
Hello World Updated Successfully
```

You can directly use the bar(new instance) via :-

```py
#node.bar.data
print(node.bar.data)
```

output will be last updated value i.e. :-

```
Hello World
```