# How to have typing support for a static property (using a decorator)

Tags: python, design-patterns, static, python-decorators, python-typing

Given a static property decorator:

```py
class static_property:
    def __init__(self, getter):
        self.__getter = getter

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return self.__getter(objtype)

    @staticmethod
    def __call__(getter_fn):
        return static_property(getter_fn)
```

That is applied to a class as follows:

```py
class Foo:
    @static_prop
    def bar(self) -> int:
        return 10
```

Add called as static:

```py
>>> print(Foo.bar)
10
```

How would I add typing support to `static_property` so `Foo.bar` is inferred as type `int` instead of as `Any`?

Or is there another way to create the decorator to support type inference?

See Also: [how-to-define-class-field-in-python-that-is-an-instance-of-a-class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56816580/1171746)

Comment: I don't think you can. `mypy` has to be specially coded to know about `property`, because what `property` does is *not* a static property of the code.

Comment: @chepner While you are right about the special case of `property`, the actual use case here is just a custom descriptor. Depending on what exactly your goals are and what you are willing to compromise on, you can definitely construct one in a generic way to allow inference of the type returned by the underlying getter. I showed a few ideas below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

My preferred solution: (tested with Python `3.9`-`3.11`)

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


R = TypeVar("R")


class static_property(Generic[R]):
    def __init__(self, getter: Callable[[], R]) -> None:
        self.__getter = getter

    def __get__(self, obj: object, objtype: type) -> R:
        return self.__getter()

    @staticmethod
    def __call__(getter_fn: Callable[[], R]) -> static_property[R]:
        return static_property(getter_fn)


class Foo:
    @static_property
    def bar() -> int:  # type: ignore[misc]
        return 10
```

Details in section 3).

---

### 0) The problem: Decorate *what* exactly?

The way your code is written currently suggests that you want to create a descriptor that you can decorate **class** methods with, as evidenced by the fact that you are passing the `objtype` to your getter function inside `__get__`.

On the other hand, the name of your descriptor class `static_property` and the fact that `bar` is effectively static (does nothing with an instance or class) suggests that you actually want to decorate **static** methods with it. That would require a very different approach.

---

### 1) Generic descriptor taking a *class* method

But first things first, the solution for the methods taking a **class** as their only argument.

This can be accomplished by making your `static_property` descriptor class **generic** in terms of the return type `R` of the method being decorated (in the following example `int` and `str`).

##### Complete working example

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Any, Generic, TypeVar


R = TypeVar("R")


class static_property(Generic[R]):
    def __init__(self, getter: Callable[[Any], R]) -> None:
        self.__getter = getter

    def __get__(self, obj: object, objtype: type) -> R:
        return self.__getter(objtype)

    @staticmethod
    def __call__(getter_fn: Callable[[Any], R]) -> "static_property[R]":
        return static_property(getter_fn)


class Foo:
    @static_property
    def bar(cls) -> int:
        return 10

    @static_property
    def baz(cls) -> str:
        return "a"


x = Foo().bar
y = Foo.baz
reveal_type(x)
reveal_type(y)
```

Running this through `mypy --strict` gives the following output:

```
note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
note: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

##### Caveat

Technically we are already encountering an issue because the `bar` and `baz` methods are still viewed as regular **instance** methods by the type checker, which means it expects the first argument to be an **instance** of `Foo`, not the class itself. This why I went with `Any` as the parameter for `Callable` in the descriptor methods.

This is not really relevant in this case since (as I mentioned above) the methods are *effectively* static anyway, so the first argument is meaningless. More importantly, since the `bar` and `baz` methods are only ever used in their **unbound** form inside the descriptor's `__get__`, the annotations are technically still correct.

---

### 2) Generic descriptor taking a *static* method

Assuming you *actually* want `static_property` to decorate static methods, meaning in this case methods that really **do not** take any arguments, this would require a different approach.

Since the built-in `staticmethod` class is a subtype of `Callable` (due to it obviously supporting the `__call__` protocol), we can decorate the `bar` and `baz` methods with `staticmethod` and pass the resulting objects to our own `static_property.__call__`.

We can keep `R` because [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/builtins.pyi) defines `staticmethod` as generic in terms of the return type of the method passed to it as well. (At least for Python `3.10+`.) This means we can retain the information about the return type of our `bar` and `baz` methods, even if we decorate them with `staticmethod`.

##### Complete working example

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


R = TypeVar("R")


class static_property(Generic[R]):
    def __init__(self, getter: Callable[[], R]) -> None:
        self.__getter = getter

    def __get__(self, obj: object, objtype: type) -> R:
        return self.__getter()

    @staticmethod
    def __call__(getter_fn: Callable[[], R]) -> "static_property[R]":
        return static_property(getter_fn)

class Foo:
    @static_property
    @staticmethod
    def bar() -> int:
        return 10

    @static_property
    @staticmethod
    def baz() -> str:
        return "a"


x = Foo().bar
y = Foo.baz
reveal_type(x)
reveal_type(y)
```

The `mypy --strict` output is still the same as in the one above, meaning the types are correctly inferred as `int` and `str` respectively.

As you can see, the getter function can now simply be annotated as `Callable[[], R]`, i.e. a callable taking no arguments, but returning our descriptor's type argument.

---

### 3) Getting rid of `staticmethod`

The final step is to make it unnecessary to use the `staticmethod` decorator altogether. Unfortunately, this can not be accomplished by *subclassing* it and explicitly defining our subclass as generic in terms of `R` again. This is mainly due to the fact that `staticmethod.__get__` returns a callable (see typeshed again for reference), but we explicitly want it to return `R`.

What stands in our way then, is that `mypy` (and presumably other type checkers) expect *every method* that is not decorated with `staticmethod` to take at least one argument. So we will get complaints, if we define `bar` and `baz` as taking *no arguments*.

So far I found no way around this other than explicitly ignoring that miscellaneous error and proceeding as follows.

##### Working example

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


R = TypeVar("R")


class static_property(Generic[R]):
    def __init__(self, getter: Callable[[], R]) -> None:
        self.__getter = getter

    def __get__(self, obj: object, objtype: type) -> R:
        return self.__getter()

    @staticmethod
    def __call__(getter_fn: Callable[[], R]) -> static_property[R]:
        return static_property(getter_fn)


class Foo:
    @static_property
    def bar() -> int:  # type: ignore[misc]
        return 10

    @static_property
    def baz() -> str:  # type: ignore[misc]
        return "a"


x = Foo().bar
y = Foo.baz
reveal_type(x)
reveal_type(y)
```

##### Obvious caveat

The types are obviously inferred correctly again, but `mypy` will complain without the `type: ignore` directives, saying `error: Method must have at least one argument`. The descriptor still works fine though and there is no actual type safety issue here. Just to be clear here, that `type: ignore` is because of the missing **parameter** in the signatures of `bar` and `baz`, which `mypy` generally considers unsafe.

The reason this is **actually type safe** here is that we are again only ever dealing with *unbound* methods `bar` and `baz`. The decorator "consumes" them, which means they will never be called bound to their class or an instance thereof. Thus, our methods do not need any arguments.

(By the way, I just used `__future__.annotations` here to avoid the quotes around `static_property[R]`. You can obviously do the same with solutions 1) and 2) above.)

##### Trade-offs everywhere

Ultimately it seems as though you'll have to decide, which solution is most useful to you. Each has its own downsides. It appears that we cannot do this in a 100 % clean way right now, but maybe someone else will find a way, or maybe the typing system will change in way to that allows a better solution.

Comment: Brilliat! Could this be extended to work with `@class_property` so that `def bar(cls) -> int:` could be decorated with `@class_property`?

Comment: Not sure why but section 2 does not work in python `3.8`.